# Problem of superimpose and how to change legend symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, symbols, legend

Given the plot as follows

[image]

I have two problems:

1. a and b are superimposed on each other, how should I make this clear on the graph?
2. How could I change legend c to other icons like star? (It looks a bit similar to a)

The code is shown below:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{semilogyaxis}[title=Random Dataset,
legend pos=outer north east,
legend style={draw=none},
xtick={1,2,...,9}, 
scaled ticks=false,
log ticks with fixed point={1000 sep=},
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
axis line style=-,
minor tick style={draw=none},
enlargelimits,
ylabel = Solving Time (ms),
xlabel = Number of Constraints,
every axis legend/.append style={xshift=-10pt}
]
\addplot plot coordinates{(1,100)(2,100)(3,100)(4,100)(5,100)(6,100)(7,100)(8,100)(9,100)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(1,100)(2,100)(3,100)(4,100)(5,100)(6,100)(7,100)(8,100)(9,100)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(1,78)(2,62)(3,41)(4,44)(5,120)(6,96)(7,133)(8,133)(9,91)};
\legend{a,b,c}
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

One way would be to change the plot styles so that both the `a` and `b` markers could be seen.  For example using a howllow `square` for `b` allows the `a` points to be visible.

For your second question, using `\addplot+[mark=triangle]` uses a triangle shape which is sufficiently different so that it won't be confused with the other markers.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{semilogyaxis}[title=Random Dataset,
legend pos=outer north east,
legend style={draw=none},
xtick={1,2,...,9}, 
scaled ticks=false,
log ticks with fixed point={1000 sep=},
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
axis line style=-,
minor tick style={draw=none},
enlargelimits,
ylabel = Solving Time (ms),
xlabel = Number of Constraints,
every axis legend/.append style={xshift=-10pt}
]
\addplot plot coordinates{(1,100)(2,100)(3,100)(4,100)(5,100)(6,100)(7,100)(8,100)(9,100)};
\addplot+[draw opacity=0.5, thick, mark=square] plot coordinates{(1,100)(2,100)(3,100)(4,100)(5,100)(6,100)(7,100)(8,100)(9,100)};
\addplot+[mark=triangle] plot coordinates{(1,78)(2,62)(3,41)(4,44)(5,120)(6,96)(7,133)(8,133)(9,91)};
\legend{a,b,c}
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The way of handling the superimpose is ingenious, cool!